# Article 'the' use in front of television

Tags: articles

[image][image]
Use of  ' the' before television???????~ above 1st photo from use of 'the' is different from 2nd photo please solve my question

Comment: One refers to the broadcast, the other to the physical device.

Comment: @JasonBassford Yes. However leaving aside the question of physical location, there is an essential difference in the way we talk about radio programmes versus those on TV. e.g. "I listen to the news on *the radio*, but I watch the news on *TV*. The pictorial example in the question is quite correct. It's one of those idiomatic oddities of which English is replete.

Answer (score 1):

In the first photo, they're talking about TV broadcasts.  "I saw him on TV" means "He appeared on a TV show," not "He was physically standing on the TV."

In the second photo, they're talking about physical location - a specific TV like the one in your house.  The show piece is stacked on top of the television, not displayed on the screen.